# Python Soap Server for the Quickbooks Webconnector

Tags: python, soap, quickbooks, soapserver

I'm writing a Soap Server to interact with the quickbooks webconnector, and I really don't even know where to start. I have the wsdl file, and a list of all the functions and arguments that the web connector needs, but I really just don't know where to start. I couldn't find any real documentation on this for python, there are some php tutorials, but that's not quite what I need. I tried using ZSI and I got it generating the files, but I had no idea how to use them. If anyone has any experience with this, I'd appreciate your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ids their some one who had hands on this cause i also try same thind with SOAPpy and proxy wsdl services but no result on this

Sample Code :

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL    
url='http://developer.intuit.com/uploadedFiles/Support/QBWebConnectorSvc.wsdl'    
proxy = WSDL.Proxy(url)
print 'Available methods:'
for method in proxy.methods.keys():    
    print method    
    ci = proxy.methods.get(method)    
    for param in ci.inparams:    
        print param.name.ljust(20), param.type    
    print
autho = proxy.authenticate(user,pass)
```

This is my fisrt hand on this cam any one guide me forward.
in this ??

Thank You